# Test directive that listens for enter key press with Angular and Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a directive that listens for keydown events in order to take action when enter is pressed, and a component using it:

onEnter directive

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[appOnEnter]'
})
export class OnEnterDirective {

    @Output() enterPressed = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
    onKeyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if ((event.which === 13)) {
            this.enterPressed.emit();
        }
    }

}
```

component.html

```
<div appOnEnter (enterPressed)=do()></div>
```

component.ts

```
export class Component {

    next = new EventEmitter<null>();

    do() {
        this.next.emit();
    }

}
```

I am trying to test this with Jasmine but the event does not seem to be triggered.

component.spec.ts

```
it('if enter is pressed action should be taken', () => {
        spyOn(component.next, 'emit');
        const event = new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
            key: 'Enter'
        });
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.next.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

The component and directive work fine, the only problem is mocking the enter press.